# how to know which file is being invoked on accessing website in tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, production-environment, rhel6, jdk6

I am currently running my applications on Tomcat 7u59 with JDK6. My developers are requesting me to deploy there class files in the production environment while I am asking them to test on the testing environment.

They are getting it tested but I am not sure whether they are getting tested the module that contains the class files they asked me to place in the production environment. And neither the testing team helps in this regard.

So, in this regard, I would like to know which files of the application are being invoked when a particular module is tested.

Could anyone help me in this regard? Any alternate suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on a linux system you can use lsof command with some grep command in pipe.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you Francesco. I am on Linux system only and of course lsof command works. But I want something like the files accessed are to be logged either in catalina.out or any other log file by increasing its log level or something like that because I can see even after some time also unlike lsof command output.